# Hugo is unable to find themes directory

Tags: hugo

In my project I have a small script that runs some build scripts to prepare my dev. But, my current configuration is causing an error. It's looking for the themes directory in the wrong location.

My build script lives in the root directory. And my hugo app lives in `frontend/`. I want to call the build script from route and have it build hugo.

```
/my-project
  /frontend
    /custom-theme
  build-script.sh
```

My `frontend/config.toml`:

```
baseURL = "https://site.local"
title = "Site Title"
themesDir = "themes"
theme = "custom-theme"
disableKinds = [ "taxonomyTerm", "taxonomy", "robotsTXT" ]
```

When I run my build script from the build directory with the following command I get an error:

```
# Build HTML and CSS
npm run build:dev --prefix $PWD/frontend/themes/custom-theme

# Hugo frontend
hugo --config $PWD/frontend/config.dev.toml

# Build PHP dependencies
composer install -d $PWD/api/
```

The error:

```
Error: Unable to find theme Directory: C:\Users\James\Projects\my-project\themes\custom-theme
```

It's missing the `\frontend` part of the path. It should be:

```
C:\Users\James\Projects\my-project\frontend\themes\custom-theme
```

Is it possible to tell hugo where to look for the themes?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Hugo is assuming your paths are relative to the current directory. You're building from the `C:\Users\James\Projects\my-project` directory, so when Hugo puts that together with your `themesDir` setting of `themes`, it gets `C:\Users\James\Projects\my-project\themes`. Instead, try setting `themesDir = "frontend\themes"`.

A corollary to this is that you will need to set all the other directory options as well if you want Hugo to behave like it would if you built from the `frontend` directory. For example, you would need to set `contentDir = "frontend\content"` and `layoutDir = "frontend\layout"`. You can check which directories are configurable in the [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/getting-started/configuration/).

A caveat, though: I haven't actually tested this myself, so if it doesn't work, that's probably why. :)